# Can we update link coloring on ELL to make linked text more easily readable?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, design

Loving the look of the site now that we've "graduated" out of beta!

In my professional life, I've become more engaged in designing for readability, and found that the WCAG contrast standards are a good minimum to hit—even irrespective of providing usability to users of all visual acuity levels  (which itself seems like a decent goal, too).

I noticed that hyperlinks on the main ELL site are sitting at a [2.86:1](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=30AA9A&bcolor=FFFFFF) contrast ratio between light green text and white background, dropping to an even less readable [2.03:1](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=45C9B8&bcolor=FFFFFF) when hovered over.

---

[image: A screenshot from WebAIM's Contrast Checker, showing a foreground (text) color of #30AA9A, a background color of #FFFFFF (white), a contrast ratio of 2.86 to 1, and failures at AA and AAA levels of compliance for normal-sized text.]

---

Are this concern and/or the associated desire shared by others? Is there a mechanism for updating the color?

Comment: Yes, I share this concern.  For a long time I did try to provide feedback on this sort of thing to SE, but their designers don't appear to be concerned with accessibility, so they've made basically no progress on this over the years and eventually I gave up on providing this sort of feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Based on our [current roadmap](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/28/the-loop-community-public-platform-roadmap-q1-2021/), we don't have immediate plans to work on this request. We'll revisit it at a later date and provide more details here when it has been prioritized and/or completed.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of issue does get discussed on the Meta Stack. If you do a search there using the user-interface tag and contrast you will find a number of posts

https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=%5buser-interface%5d%20contrast

A recent one which seems directly of interest to your issue is

[Low contrast text --- doesn't meet WCAG standards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341277/low-contrast-text-doesnt-meet-wcag-standards)

Note that it has been around there for more than a year and the site has not taken action over the request.

Thanks to ColleenV here are two more links which may be more relevant

[Visited links should be more visible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52942/visited-links-should-be-more-visible)

[Links to visited titles of questions in new search results need more contrast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164746/links-to-visited-titles-of-questions-in-new-search-results-need-more-contrast)

Comment: The link you've included is about inactive text, which is excluded from accessibility contrast requirements. This one might be better: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164746/links-to-visited-titles-of-questions-in-new-search-results-need-more-contrast or maybe https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52942/visited-links-should-be-more-visible they're both about links, but they're both pretty old.